# swap function working incorrectly with quicksort code

Tags: c, sorting

I am testing my quicksort code in C(which calculates the number of swaps that this function has to make while sorting), which is not providing correct result. 
I narrowed it down to my swap function.When swap function get first = 3 and second = 3.Its final result becomes first = 0 and second = 0.
When tested separatly this function works fine.Below is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int arr[SIZE];

void quicksort(int start, int end);
long int answer = 0;    

int main(){
    int i, input;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    quicksort(0, SIZE - 1);
    printf("%ld\n", answer);
    return  0;
}


void quicksort(int start, int end){
    void swap(int * first, int * second);
    int partition(int start, int end);
    int pos;
    if(start >= end)return;
    else{
        pos = partition(start, end);
        quicksort(start, pos - 1);
        quicksort(pos + 1, end);
        answer += (end - start);
    }
}

void swap(int * first, int * second){
    printf("start = %d , end = %d\n",*first, *second);
    *first = *first ^ *second;
    *second = *first ^ *second;
    *first = *first ^ *second;
        printf("start = %d , end = %d\n",*first, *second);
}

int findpivot(int start, int end){
    return start;
}

int partition(int start, int end){
    int findpivot(int start, int end);
    int i = 0;
    int pivot_pos = findpivot(start, end);
    int pivot = arr[pivot_pos];
    int pos = pivot_pos + 1;
    for(i = pivot_pos + 1 ; i <= end; i++){
        if(arr[i] <= pivot){
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[pos]);       
                pos++;  
            }
    }
    pos--;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    swap(&arr[pivot_pos], &arr[pos]);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("getting out\n");
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using XOR (^) for your swap function? Why not something like `int temp = *first; *first = *second; *second = temp;`

Comment: You've also declared function prototypes inside other functions, these need to be defined on the global scope.

Comment: I know of the second alternative but i want to know the reason why this does not work.As for function prototype i have used style of C programming book by ritchie.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know this warning for using xorswap.I can see this is what happening in my function.You saved me another hour of futile debugging

Answer (score 1):

From [programmers.stackexchange.com/a/182043](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/182043)

> When using xorswap there's a danger of supplying same variable as both arguments to the function which zeroes out the said variable due to it being xor'd with itself which turns all the bits to zero. Of course this itself would result in unwanted behavior regardless of algorithm used, but the behavior might be surprising and not obvious at first glance.

So your fix is to check if both arguments are equal.